# Loading image into panel from database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, image-loading

My application saves image data in database and when loading information into form, it loads image into panel. This is working fine. But in case if user doesn't want to save image, I've inserted '0' in image field (varbinary) in database. While loading this information (0x00000000) from database it throws the following exception:

*"Parameter is not valid."*

Here I am giving some pieces of code:

Saving image in database:

```
if(user has selected an image)
{
   Byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePatient);
   sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Img", imageBytes); //Img is database column for images
}
else
{
   sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Img", 0);
}
```

Loading image from database:

```
Byte[] imageData = new Byte[0];
imageData = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables["Patients"].Rows[0]["Img"]);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
panelImage.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

I've tried to put some check which will allow to load BackgroundImage if and only if data is not of the zeros form.

Please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would store a `NULL` instead of `0`.

```
if(user has selected an image) 
{ 
   Byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePatient); 
   sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Img", imageBytes); //Img is database column for images 
} 
else 
{ 
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("Img", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1 );
    sqlCommand.Parameters["Img"].Value = DbNull.Value;
}
```

And then use an `if` statement to check if it's non-null:

```
Byte[] imageData = new Byte[0]; 
imageData = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables["Patients"].Rows[0]["Img"]); 
if(imageData != null)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData); 
    panelImage.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream); 
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx

Comment: Don't you think storing NULL is an appropriate option?

Comment: In this case it is appropriate because you are saying "There is no data here"

Comment: I've 10 columns in this database table.

Comment: Perhaps you should use DBNull.Value not null, [On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) look at the community comments

Comment: @Steve Excellent point, I've updated the answer to reflect this.  Thanks

Comment: "Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Comment: @MuhammadAliDildar Is the varbinary(max) column marked as NULLABLE?  Also, I updated the answer once more to fix the issue you mentioned.

Comment: Please try the updated code I posted.  If you still get an error, make sure to mark that column as `NULL`.  And if you get an error after both steps, let us know and we will go from there.  Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadAliDildar Were you able to get this working?  If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as Accepted.  If not, let me know how I can help more.

Comment: @msigman- Thank you very much for your support. Your solution was helpful but missing one thing. I do not want to put null value in Image field. Please tell me if I can handle this issue. Thanks.